# Unable to print multiline output with HEREDOC php by using XAMPP

Tags: php, heredoc

I'm not able to print php multiline output with the "<<<" command using XAMPP. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
<?php
    echo <<<STAMPA
        stringa di output su 

        più linee che verrà stampata
        come scritta, preservando gli spazi.
STAMPA; // la chiusura del comando deve essere a inizio riga
?>
```

I tried by putting the closing tag at the beginning of the line, but it didn't work

Comment: <?php
 echo <<<HEREDOC
 non mi fa
 multiline
   output
HEREDOC;
?>

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, please edit your question and format it using MarkDown.

Comment: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What does "not able to" actually mean here? What output did you get? What output did you expect? Are you running this on the command line, or via a browser? Remember in a browser, the output is treated as HTML, and in HTML a line break is `<br>`, which heredoc won't output for you.

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/LmbK5) but if it's being sent to a browser, browsers use `<br>`, not regular line endings, for new lines.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP manual here is the rule prior to php7.3.0 :

> Warning
> Prior to PHP 7.3.0, it is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a new line as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including macOS. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a new line.

Remove the comments after the closing identifier even remove the space after it. You can only put a newline character after the semicolon.